# Ionic tabs icons are jumping/flickering

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

I am new to ionic, in my project i am using ion-tabs.
In that i using custom images as tabs icons, there are two images for each tab i.e. one for icon-on and another for icon-off.
The issue is, while clicking on tab tab icon gets larger and again after few milliseconds it is normal i.e. on same position means it is jumping or flickering.
So I don't want icons to be jump, it stays on its original fixed position.
please help me if any one have solution for the same.

My updated question
**style.css**

```
.tabs .tab-item .icon.home {  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: 50%;  
  height: 80%;  
  background-image: url("../img/App icons/home.png");  
  background-size:contain;  
}  
.tabs .tab-item .icon.home-selected {  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: 50%;  
  height: 80%;  
  background-image: url("../img/App icons/home-selected.png");  
  background-size:contain;  
}
```

tabs code in my **menu.html**

```
<ion-tabs>  
      <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="home" icon-on="home-selected" href="#/app/home">  
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"-></ion-nav-view>  
      </ion-tab>  
</ion-tabs>
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: care to share screenshot or code plz.

Comment: @Dev, thanks for comment,   I updated my question